# Html purifier clears p tag

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation, htmlpurifier

For some reason html purifier clears p tags. It happens when p is inside of span tags.
For example:

```
<span class=\"large gray content_text article_text\">
<p>111111</p>
<p>222222</p>
<p>333333</p>
</span>
```

Output:

```
<span>111111

2222222

3333333</span>
```

My htmlpurifier config:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config -> set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config -> set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config -> set('HTML.TidyLevel','none');
$config -> set('HTML.Allowed', 'p, a[href|rel], span[style], img[src|style], object[height|width|data], param[name|value|allowscriptaccess|allowfullscreen|height|width], br, strong, em');
$config -> set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'font-weight, font-style, text-decoration, color, width, height');
$config -> set('HTML.SafeObject', 'true');
$config -> set('Output.FlashCompat', 'true');
$config -> set('HTML.FlashAllowFullScreen', 'true');
$schemes = array('http' => true, 'https' => true);
$config -> set('URI.AllowedSchemes', $schemes);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$content = $purifier -> purify($content);
```

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes in <span> tag, do you?

Comment: First of all `<p>` inside a `<span>` this format is wrong. You can not define a block level element `<p>` inside an  inline element `<span>`. W3c doesn't validate this.

Comment: Oh I did stripslashes on span. Just copy-pasted from old example where slashes still existed.

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` is an inline element, it's incorrect to put block level `<p>` tags inside of it.

Use `<div>` instead of `<span>`.

Comment: I don't do this. It's user input. I try to clear it but preserve some text formatting.

Comment: @inwoker You can try to use Core.EscapeInvalidTags and then replace &lt;p&gt; with <p> and so on, but it's not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, HTML Purifier should have output:

```
<span class="large gray content_text article_text"></span>
<p><span class="large gray content_text article_text">111111</span></p>
<p><span class="large gray content_text article_text">222222</span></p>
<p><span class="large gray content_text article_text">333333</span></p>
<span class="large gray content_text article_text"></span>
```